# Business Catalyst responsive gallery

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, business-catalyst

I have done about 20 websites which included the Business Catalyst gallery module. This is the first one that I'm having problems with and I don't know why. Please check out: http://topspindenver.businesscatalyst.com/gallery.html.

You will notice that if you make the window smaller, the gallery thumbnails start overflowing the window. In every other website that I've done, the gallery was responsive within the specified skeleton columns, and the thumbnails automatically get smaller, like on this site: http://mountaingardendiva.com/.

Does anyone know why this is happening only on this site? I have already tried specifically targeting the table that the thumbnails sit in and given it a `max-width:100%`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just let me know are you talking about [Responsive Business Templates](http://webresponsivedesigns.com.au/responsive-business-templates/), If you find this useful then let me know....ok

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using Firefox to view this site and noticing this problem for the first time, because it looks fine in Chrome. It has to do with how Firefox computes the width of a table and the max-width of images within the table. You can solve the problem by applying a max-width to td.photogalleryitem with each media query that changes the page width.

Answer (score 0):

It does work in Chrome, but to make it work in FireFox try setting the css on your images to width:100% instead of max-width:100%